# How to view the parameterized query generated by Node-postgres?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, node-postgres

I've been facing an error with a query I'm trying to pass using the node-postgres library. I'm following the basic premise of a parameterized query as stated in their docs:

```
let sql = 'insert into reviews(review_details, source_id, datePublished) values ($1, $2, $3)'
let values = [reviewDetails, source, date]

client.query(sql, values)
  .then(({ rows }) => { resolve(rows) })
  .catch((err) => { reject(err) })
```

The query fails when it tries to insert the json value of `reviewDetails`, with an error saying: `invalid input syntax for type json`. The error detail says: `Token "'" is invalid.`. So it seems as though there's a point in the json where a single quote character is not being escaped.

The json is pretty big, so I can't say for sure where this error is happening. I was trying to print out the final formatted statemtent generated by node-postgres and paste it into pgAdmin to experiment with the query and see where exactly it is failing.

However when I run `console.log(sql)` it returns the string exactly as I wrote it (with $1, $2, $3 instead of the values that were passed). Is there a way to log the query generated by the library?